# Datatables Filtering with YADCF - Custom button triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yadcf

I am tying to use the [YADCF](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf) extension so that I can sort the data in my table by it's status. I want to be able to click a button (bootstrap pills) and for that to then be the trigger for filtering the data, however I can't figure out how to do so. Below you can see an example from [WHMCS](http://demo.whmcs.com/), this is what I wish to happen
[image]

Currently I have been able to filter the data but only by using a select drop down. As you can see below, this is how my table and buttons look (including the added Select element from YADCF)
[image]

I was able to have the Select element work fully, but what I am asking is: how can I get each individual button/pill trigger a filter for each type of status?

This is the code I have for the table so far

```
yadcf.init(ticketsTable, [
    {
        column_number: 2,
        filter_container_id: 'test_container_0',
        column_data_type: "html",
        html_data_type: "text",
        filter_default_label: "Select Status"

    },
],
    {
        externally_triggered: false
    }
);
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to achieve is *custom pills* you don't need to use my yadcf plugin at all, you can use the simple Datatables api alone, see the [following jsbin sample](http://jsbin.com/pojimukijo/1/edit?html,js,output) and see code snippet:

```
var oTable;
function myPillFilter(data) {
  oTable.columns(0).search(data).draw();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

---

But if you want to use the yadcf plugin...

Your should add a filter for that column and make it hidden and add *several* buttons / spans / etc with `onclick` event that will call yadcf external api [exFilterColumn](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L267)

See the following [quick jsbin sample I made](http://jsbin.com/rixikoleqi/edit?html,js,output)

code snippets:

```
var oTable;
function myPillFilter(data) {
    yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[0, data]]);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable().yadcf([
    {column_number : 0, filter_container_id: "some_data"}]);
});



<div onclick="myPillFilter('Some Data 1')">
   some-1
</div>
<div onclick="myPillFilter('Some Data 2')">
   some-2
</div>
```

Comment: I have used your first example as something to work off and I must say that in the end it has worked very well, I appreciate the quick reply and very detailed documentation and examples. You helped me a lot.

Comment: any way to make it work with check boxes? I need to filter by multiple values.

Comment: @SamiaRuponti you can use multi_select with chosen / select2 plugins , [see first column in showcase](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_select2.html)